# After upgrading to 16.04 from 14.04, php7 installation fails

Tags: upgrade, 16.04, php7

I want to install php7 after upgrading to 16.04 from 14.04. Here is what I get:

```
Setting up php7.0-fpm (7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.2) ...
Job for php7.0-fpm.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status php7.0-fpm.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
    invoke-rc.d: initscript php7.0-fpm, action "start" failed.
    dpkg: error processing package php7.0-fpm (--configure):
     subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     php7.0-fpm
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The output of `sudo php-fpm7.0 -t` is:

```
[07-Aug-2016 10:32:35] ERROR: failed to open configuration file '/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf': No such file or directory (2)
[07-Aug-2016 10:32:35] ERROR: failed to load configuration file '/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf'
[07-Aug-2016 10:32:35] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for inconvenience,

**NOTE:** i used php7 in 14.04 and removed it and install php5 again. and now i want t install php7 again.

To solve this:

1. Remove php7.0-fpm: `sudo apt-get remove php7.0-fpm`
2. Purge it: `sudo apt-get purge php7.0-fpm`
3. Manually remove /etc/php/7.0/fpm directory: `sudo rm -rf /etc/php/7.0/fpm/`
4. Install php7.0-fpm again: `sudo apt-get install php7.0-fpm`

Comment: This does not work for me. After trying the 4 steps above, I still get the same error, reported in the Question.

Comment: Use synaptic to search for any old php package, and remove it.

Comment: There are no other PHP packages installed. I think my problem relates to using a linux container. see http://askubuntu.com/questions/822436/errors-installing-php7-0-fpm-on-ubuntu-16-04-running-in-a-container