# Errors installing php7.0-fpm on Ubuntu 16.04 running in a container

Tags: apt, 16.04, php7, container

On attempting to install php7.0-fpm

```
# apt-get install php7.0-fpm
```

I'm getting the following error (copied from `/var/log/apt/term.log`):

```
Preparing to unpack .../php7.0-fpm_7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php7.0-fpm (7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.2) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up php7.0-fpm (7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.2) ...

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini with new version
invoke-rc.d: initscript php7.0-fpm, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package php7.0-fpm (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 php7.0-fpm
```

So a problem exists, but what is causing it?

As suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/767563/190877), I've tried the following, but no error is found:

```
root@ubuntu:/etc/apt# /usr/sbin/php-fpm7.0 --test
[08-Sep-2016 08:44:44] NOTICE: configuration file /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf test is successful
```

I've also tried removing and reinstalling php7.0-fpm, as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/809154/190877), but this made no difference.

Can you suggest how to fix this error? Are there some more helpful error messages somewhere?

UPDATE:

This is happening when installing php7.0 on a linux container. The error does not occur when installing on a Virtual Machine from the same hosting provider.  So, perhaps the installation is attempting to set something that is "out of bounds" for the container.

My "workaround" is to use a VM instead of a container :-)

Answer (score 3):

I've ran into a similar issue while using a Elastichosts Container Server (Arachsys container). The only way to get php7.0-fpm to 'talk' what is wrong, is to start it by hand in daemon mode:

`/usr/sbin/php-fpm7.0 -D`

This produced an error regarding a missing socket file:

`ERROR: unable to bind listening socket for address '/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock': No such file or directory (2)`

As it turns out the directory `/run/php` never got created during install. Creating it by hand and giving it the correct owner (www-data) has solved the issue for me (after a reboot).

Answer (score 0):

Create a directory for sock-file:

```
mkdir -p /var/run/
```

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! On my system, `/var/run` is a symlink to `/run`. Should it really be a standalone directory?

Comment: Hi! Just look where php-fpm want create yourself sock-file and sure that directory is exists.